# How would you describe a character that is ‘dogmatic’ without referring to religion or politics?

Tags: fiction, characters, technique

I am trying to develop a character who has a very rigid world view but I want to use more than just a single adjective to bring out this character’s “quality”.  I also do not want to inject any religious or political inclination that the character has adopted that the rigidity can be attributed as a source.  Given this task, is there a sentence or two that you can suggest that conveys to the reader that this character is rigid without coming out and just saying so?

Note: I’m not asking for someone to write a sentence for my book.  But I’ve hit a wall and the only thing I can do right now is walk away from my typewriter.  We’ve all been there.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this in a sentence or two, rather than reveal it in the character's behaviour throughout the story?

Comment: The character is a minor character and has a small part in the life of the novel. I was really asking for one or two sentences that I could use as a guideline or basis from which I can further develop on the character (and hopefully get me past this ‘wall.

Comment: This is borderline asking what to write, but I won't downvote. I would need an impractical amount of context to give an answer. Still show-don't-tell, with every thing said about or by the character being very OCD. Something like, "It's 11.98 units long, plus or minus 0.02. But you might as well call it twelve, since imprecise people always do." Or the Hercule Poirot version, ala Murder on the Orient Express, wanting two perfectly identical eggs, and no one can get them identical enough for him.

Comment: @DWKraus great input.  You could put that as an answer as your suggestions were helpful in getting me “unblocked”.

Comment: @DWKraus That's not what OCD means...

Comment: @DM_with_secrets Forgive my vernacular, but OCD as an expression and obsessive-compulsive disorder are admittedly two different things. I was using the common expression usage,  and not expressing an opinion about mental illness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me throw this at you, not as a suggestion for what to write, but as a writing prompt regarding this or a similar character:

> He was a typical martinet--such a stickler for everything being just right that he would rather eat a cold meal than have one pea out of place on his plate.

Comment: I’ll take it … it will help to get me “moving” again … I’m off to my typewriter … thx